# Share information documenting the architecture

Tags: document-management, documentation-generator

One of the most important things in a company with a complex architecture is share information across different teams. The documentation helps the new people have joined the company, the handover, the analisys etc etc..

I'm searching for a software that allows the creation of visual documentation in which could be possible to move through different layers of details.

I imagine the general architecture diagram in which is clearly defined the relationship between all the components (microservices communicating with API boxes, cloud services or databases and so on). Simply selecting a particular component (the spring-boot spring-batch instance or the elasticsearch box or the angular front-end), the level of details increases. The internal structure of the current module in terms of Network (type of server, balancer ..), Flowchart, Entity-Relationship, User interface etc etc. The enhancement the these details ends in very detailed info about server configurations for the local env, spring security roles, spring batch cron expressions and so on ..

I'm asking too much, isn't it?

Comment: Well, maybe you didn't provide sufficient details: What OS must it run on, what price margin do you have, which features do you need?

Comment: I was thinking more about a cloud service rather than a stand alone software. In terms of budget companies spend a lot of money in Enterprise suites e.g. Atlassian - Confluence.

Comment: "cloud service" as in "runs on other people's computer" – or as in "self-hosted web service"? After all, it's comanby know-how you're talking about. Not sure if you want to store that on "other people's computer". If self-hosted, the environment might be relevant – unless you say you don't care and, if needed, simply would buy the corresponding hardware & OS etc. to run it on ;)